# Why 'make gconfig' does not work while compiling the kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile vanilla Linux kernel 3.12.14 downloaded from kernel.org. When I try `make gconfig`, it says:

```
* Unable to find the GTK+ installation. Please make sure that
* the GTK+ 2.0 development package is correctly installed...
* You need gtk+-2.0, glib-2.0 and libglade-2.0.
*
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'scripts/kconfig/.tmp_gtkcheck', needed by `scripts/kconfig/gconf.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [gconfig] Error 2
```

Now it seems my Ubuntu doesn't have gtk+ by default, `dpkg -s xxxx` confirmed it. I tried installing all 3 of these using `sudo apt-get install xxxx` but no packages found.

What can I do now! (Is pygtk an answer?)

NOTE: xxxx is place holder for 3 missing packages named in the error.

Comment: trying to compile vanilla linux kernel 3.12.14 downloaded from kernel.org. That doesn't matter if compilation is giving an error of that sort.
Next 'xxxx' is placeholder for 3 packages clearly mentioned in the error and my statement already. gtk+-2.0, glib-2.0 and libglade-2.0.

Last about development packages, no I am not sure about that, I think I haven't. What is needed to be installed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The message is very clear:

```
* Unable to find the GTK+ installation. Please make sure that
* the GTK+ 2.0 development package is correctly installed...
* You need gtk+-2.0, glib-2.0 and libglade-2.0.
*
```

So, just install the libraries you need. In most cases, these are provided by the `-dev` version of the packages mentioned in the error, in the case of libraries is likely that you have to add `lib` at the start. So, in this case:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglade2-dev
```

And done.

Comment: When you aren't used to it, it's not so clear how to determine the names of the packages you need (`gtk+-2.0` → `libgtk2.0-dev`, etc.)

Comment: Package libglib2.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin

Package libgtk2.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgtk2.0-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libglib2.0-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libglade2-dev

Comment: Not done :(
I listed some issues above, the errors I got about packages not available.

Comment: I used (`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin`) for gtk and glib and it turns out I already have their latest versions. I am unable to locate libglade though by any means, trouble!!!

Comment: @Waqar then you have other troubles apart building the kernel, restore your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the original, run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: So it turns out that it was related to sources, not exactly the list file, but the main source was causing problems. I had to go to software center and change the server manually to make `apt-get install` working and then its all sorted out. Thanks everyone :)    
@Braiam if you add something about this sources list / server into your answer, I will mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Waqar I would not, since there isn't anything stated in your question that would be relevant to that problem and in a *normal* case the instructions will work out without intervention ;)